# Position doesn't highlight when I use it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables

```js
  creditCardValidation = event => {
      const targetValue = event.target.value.replace(/[^\d0-9]/g, '');
      const length = event.target.value.length;
      let position = event.target.selectionEnd;

      event.target.value = targetValue.replace(/(.{4})/g, '$1 ').trim();
      event.target.selectionEnd = position += 
      event.target.value.charAt(position - 1) === ' ' &&
      event.target.value.charAt(length - 1) === ' ';
 };
```

position doesn't highlight I use it in the next context --> event.target.selectionEnd = **position** += event.target.value.charAt

Comment: I've seen minified code that was more clear than your last line. And I don't understand what your problem is. So, let's pretend for a moment that you're talking to people that have no idea what you're doing and see this code for the first time. What are you trying to do? what doesn't work? what do you expect? and what do you get?

Comment: To be really really really sure that your first regex matches everything but digits you could also include the unicode selectors for the digits: `/[^\d0-9\u0030-\u0039]/g` or you simply use `/\D/g`

Comment: I need to get rid of double appropriation or to get rid of position at all. Because if I put event.target.selectionEnd instead of position, it doesn't work